# Entries take a long time to update on live site. EE 1.6.8

Tags: control-panel, ee1, performance

My organization's site in running EE 1.6.8 hosted on Rackspace Cloud Sites.  In the last few weeks we have noticed that it takes longer and longer to update an entry in the control panel.  We are now at approximately 20-30 seconds from the time we click "Update" to when we get the preview screen verifying the entry has been updated.  Other aspects of the CP load quickly like opening entries or viewing entries in a particular category.

Strange thing is that we have a staging version of the site also hosted on Rackspace Cloud Sites that has its own database but it is just a copy of the live site and the stage site CP updates entries quickly - 2 seconds max.

The front end of both run okay as well.  For some reason it just seems like the live site hangs when writing new info to the DB.

Here is the debug info from the bottom of the preview screen of an updated entry:

> ExpressionEngine 1.6.8 - © Copyright 2003 - 2009 - EllisLab, Inc.
>   Script executed in 0.4475 seconds   19 SQL queries used
>   Build:  20090915

0.4475 seconds ?  More like 25 seconds in real time.

If both sites have the same DB, site files, addons etc what are your guesses for the slowness?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Several things to look at:

1. If you are using EE caching on templates (page or tag), try disabling all caching. EE clears the cache when entries are saves so it's possible there is a hangup with the clearing. Make sure your cache directory is set to 777.
2. Take a look at the Network tab in Firefox to see what you can see. You're looking for any errors or any part of the page load that is getting delayed.
3. Open phpMyAdmin or whatever tool you use for connecting to the DB and run a SHOW PROCESSLIST query while you are saving an entry to see if there is some holdup with a specific query. In phpMyAdmin, you can also load the Processes tab to see this info (http://screencast.com/t/G7DONsI7Fu9). If you keep refreshing that page as the editing delay is occurring, you can see updated info.
4. Check your php error log. There may be clues there.

Comment: Awesome.  Will try some of this and report back.

Comment: Also, I'd get your install to 1.7.3 and make sure your addons are up-to-date.